# Swift stdlib tool Error: Expected a single Swift ABI version in

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I am getting this error on compilation with Xcode 8.3.3(8E3004b) and Swift 3.1:

[image: error message]

The end of the compile log looks like:

```
Copy Swift standard libraries into app

CopySwiftLibs /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/.../InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/...

cd /Users/.../Desktop/...

export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk

builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign 5E5A51CAC2539864509F6653B0DC104FE3A518D1 --scan-executable /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/.../InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/.../... --scan-folder /Users/jpower/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAFIPS-cdqhmsienumzxcdzytsdwwwawavl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/.../InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/.../Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/.../InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/.../PlugIns --scan-folder /Users/.../Desktop/.../Carthage/Build/iOS/Alamofire.framework --scan-folder /Users/.../Desktop/.../Carthage/Build/iOS/ObjectMapper.framework --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/.../InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/.../Frameworks --unsigned-destination /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/.../BuildProductsPath/SwiftSupport
```

The weird things is I don't have this error when I compile with Xcode 9.0 beta(9M136h) and Swift 3.2, also, I can build success before today.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a carthage issue. It's being discussed here: [issue #2062](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2062)

The workaround I use is to open: `~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/` and delete everything before doing another `carthage update`

Answer (score 0):

I found that I restart my Mac and the question is gone, hope this can help someone.

But I still don't know what's the problem, so still looking for explain, if someone know why, please let me know.